# Unable to Build Android APK in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I just downloaded Unity3D yesterday. I am trying to build the APK for my game, all looks fine (the game is even working fine on my device in the Unity Remote for Android), but when I try to build the APK for the game, I get this error in the Console:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. See the Console for details.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:/Android SDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files (x86)/Unity/Editor/Data/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer\sdktools.jar" -

 stderr[
 Error: java.io.EOFException
 ]
 stdout[
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/build-failure-eofexception.212784/

seems like this issue is related to the JDK version you are running, you did not state what JDK version you are using but according to the link above you should try using JDK 1.6.0_45. also, assuming you did not do it already, make sure that the JAVA_HOME env. variable is defined correctly on your system.

Comment: Hi, how can I make sure that the JAVA_HOME env. variable is defined correctly on my system? I am a beginner so if you could help me with the exact step by step process, it would be great

Comment: I was able to set the env. variable, but in the Variable Value, should I set the path for JRE or JDK? Also, I have JDK version 1.6.0_45. I also have two JRE versions (JRE 6 and JRE 7). Which version should I use for the path?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is an old question.

You have to check Console section, in bottom of the screen. There is always an extra comment before this error.

For example it could be duo to wrong key file path, which produces the same error.

Answer (score -1):

***To verify JAVA_HOME is correctly defined:***
open cmd (shortcut winKey+R, type 'cmd' + press enter), type 'echo '%JAVA_HOME%' and press enter. if you get the path to your jdk your ok (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75' is mine). if you get '%JAVA_HOME% that means that it is not defined.

***To define JAVA_HOME (in windows):***

open control panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings (left pannel). in the opened dialog press the 'Environment Variables' button (at the bottom), then in the 'system variables' section press 'New...' and add the following:
in 'Variable name': JAVA_HOME
in 'Variable value': , for example if you installed the jdk in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk enter that in the 'Variable value' field.

press Ok to create the varaible, then OK again to close the 'Envrionment variables' dialog and then ok again to close the system properties dialog.

you can test it following that steps described at the beginning (using the cmd) - just don't forget to close + re-open the cmd window so that your changes will take affect.

Comment: I have checked, it is correctly defined. It shows the path to C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_45

Comment: I have tried building the APK in Unity again, same error